# Maya scripting is it case sensitives?

Tags: maya

Maya software scripting is it case sensitives ? I want to Say is it possible to add the codes from Mouse actions scripts without respected cases sensitives ? IAM New to Maya 3d.

Comment: why would you want to do that?

Comment: I want to list all Maya codes from mouse action script to create randomly Real fx by exemple list all mouse action script by incremented all lign of code. Sory for my english.